# How to use PageRank algorithm in JUNG?

Tags: jung, pagerank

I am using JUNG as my tool to visualize network graph and compute network attributes(ex: indegree, outdegree, and pagerank).

I know JUNG already implemented PageRank algorithm, but there were no instruction on using pagerank algorithm in the manual(http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html).

Does anyone knows how to do it?

I also tried the following code, but it came out an error "**Vertex CLP Holdings Ltd not an element of this graph**".

```
public void calcPageRank()
{
   PageRank<MyNode, MyLink> alg = new PageRank<MyNode, MyLink>(g,0.1);
   alg.initialize();
   System.out.println(alg.getVertexScore(new MyNode(53084,"CLP Holdings Ltd")));    
}
```

code file is [here](http://pastie.org/3619947)

THX!!

Comment: Actually if you build JUNG by checking out via m2e Maven SVN SCM connector taken from http://code.google.com/p/jung/source/checkout, it has unit tests for classes under `edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.scoring` package which include [TestPageRank](http://code.google.com/p/jung/source/browse/trunk/jung/jung-algorithms/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/scoring/TestPageRank.java) unit test class and [TestPageRankWithPriors](http://code.google.com/p/jung/source/browse/trunk/jung/jung-algorithms/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/scoring/TestPageRankWithPriors.java) unit test class

Comment: Hi eee, I still confused about how to use pagerank algorithm in JUNG. Could you give some specific solution based on my code? I traced the code(AbstractIterativeScorer.java) and suspected that I use different data structure in my program(MyNode). It leads pagerank algorithm can't find my vertex in the graph and threw IllegalArgumentException exception. thanks~

Comment: Have you looked at the Javadoc?  Or the tutorial?  As for the error you got, best guess is either (a) that vertex is actually not in your graph, or (b) you have not defined equals() and hashCode() in a compatible fashion in your MyNode class.  (Side note: "initialize()"?  I assume you mean "evaluate()".

Comment: I have read the Javadoc and the example code from eee. I am really sure that vertex is in the graph but the program couldn't find any vertex. I already defined equals() which used for comparing the MyNode class. But it seems the program still compared Mynode class in default way. Instead of initiating a new Mynode, i used the node stored in my pre-defined ArrayList and it works! alg.getVertexScore(new MyNode(53084,"CLP Holdings Ltd"))----> ERROR,   alg.getVertexScore(CompanyNodeList.get(1))---> OK   I have no idea what to do now.    Joshua O'Madadhain, thanks for your comment.

Comment: note: Your assumption is right, I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Example here:

- https://github.com/castagna/mr-pagerank/blob/master/src/main/java/com/talis/labs/pagerank/jung/JungPageRank.java